# Mean energy of ideal gas using MonteCarlo methods (from Mark Newmann - Computational Physics )

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas

while trying to replicate Mark Newman's book problems I found this problem about the Monte Carlo simulation of an ideal gas (example 10.3) where the goal is to calculate the internal energy of the gas. I start calculating the energy of a particle in a 3d cubic box of side L, which is $E=\frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2mL}(n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2)$, so if the gas has N particles, the total energy is the sum of each of their energies. I understand the algorithm used but I don't understand why the mean energy, after the MC simulation is approximately between the 25000's (using $m=\hbar=L=1$ and $kT=10$ for 1000 particles), when the mean energy of an ideal gas would supposedly give $\frac{3}{2}nkT=\frac{3}{2}1000(10)=1500$, which only happens at the beginning of this simulation because it starts on the ground state.

Is there an analytical way (on paper) I can demonstrate that the average energy after the simulation is going to be approx 250000? I tried using the definition of mean energy, $E=\frac{1}{Z}\sum_0^\infty E_n e^{-\beta E_n}$ with $E_n\approx 3\frac{\pi^2}{2}n_i^2$, considering the $n_i$'s take the same value of i in the i-th iteration (I did 250000 iterations) and i get approximately 28000, that is still far and probably incorrect to consider, but then again I would be using a computer to calculate when I want to prove it on paper.

I hope I'm being clear enough but tl;dr I want to calculate, on paper, the average internal energy of an ideal gas after a Monte Carlo simulation.

(I attach the plot obtained for the simulation, and the problem explanation)[image: plot]

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. You refer to quantum formulas for the ideal gas eigenvalues on one side. On the other side, you should be in a classical regime (without that, the equipartition theorem would not hold). Please, clarify how the quantum formulas are used.

Comment: I am considering an ideal gas (of N particles that don't interact) so I start off by obtaining the energy of a particle, that has 3 quantum numbers nx, ny and nz, as if it was confined in a cubic box. So I used Schrodinger's equation to obtain an expression for the energy of each particle. I forgot to add it but here is the header of the problem https://i.imgur.com/xmujCCO.png